# Knockout.js not updating view from dynamic ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I am trying to get knockout.js to update my view after an ajax call but having no luck.  I keep getting the error below.  It errors at `app.interactive.updateBindings`.  The parseBindingAttribute viewModel parameter is undefined.

Error:

> Unable to parse binding attribute. Message:
>   ReferenceError: `interactive` is not defined;
>   Attribute value: `template: { name: 'answerTmpl', foreach: interactive.answers }`

Dynamic HTML:

```html
<div id="questions">
    <div id="answers" data-bind="template: { name: 'answerTmpl', foreach: interactive.answers }">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    app.viewModel.interactive.answers(@Html.Raw(@Model.Answers.ToJson()));
    app.interactive.updateBindings(document.getElementById('answers'));

</script>
<script id="answerTmpl" type="text/html">
<div>
  <span></span>  <input type="checkbox" name="Answer" />
</div>
</script>
```

My .js file:

```
(function (app, $, undefined) {

    app.viewModel = {};
    app.interactive = {};
    app.interactive.callback = function () { };

 app.viewModel.interactive = {
        content: ko.observable('test'),
        answers: ko.observableArray()
    };

        app.interactive.init = function () {

        ko.applyBindings(app.viewModel);
    };

    app.interactive.updateBindings = function (element) {
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element);
    };

    app.interactive.init();

})(window.app = window.app || {}, jQuery);
```

I can fixit with the below code:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, null, app.viewModel);
```

But now I am getting this error:

> invalid 'in' operand jQuery.template

```
if (templateId in jQuery['template'])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I feel like an idiot.  I didn't even reference the jquery template script.

Comment: oops. at least you were big enough to admit it, fair play.

Comment: Wow... I just had the exact same error. For the exact same reason. Well, this turned out to be a useful answer and question for me :)

Comment: Same here. It kept working on localhosts only but when accessing the page from another server it gave same error. I had the file there but also just missing the script reference in my view which fixed it. Thank you for posting your solution. +1 ;p

Answer (score 0):

It looks a little confusing.  You have **app.viewModel.interactive** and then **app.interactive**.  I could well be missing something but would you try to applyBindings to more simply namespaced viewmodel and work up from there?

Comment: I wanted to have a namespaced viewmodel in case I used differnent files.  The app.interactive is a certain view while app is a global one for all pages.  I do think it may be a namespace issue, but I have got the namespace to work on other projects.  If I have multiple files wanting to bind then they would just use app.viewModel.{unique name}.